# What is a good way for Ruby integration tests to test javascript that does not change the DOM?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, integration-testing

I am developing a Spree (Ruby on Rails) extension that adds a javascript tag to the page.
This javascript has no visual or apparant effects for the user; it is a [piwik tracking script](http://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide).

I want to write some integration tests for this. What is a good way to test javascript that does not change the DOM?

#### Problem: No visual or other DOM changes.

Normally, javascript will be tested in the page with code like `expect(page).to have_selector 'select.ajax-filled option#detroid'` for when a piece of javascript is expected to add a "detroid" option to a select. Yet, in this case, the JS does not change the DOM visually.

A possible factor to ease this testing, is the fact the **setup** of the tracking-code is simple and predictable. My test does not need to see if running the externally included javascript `piwik.js` is actually ran correctly.

My integration tests are good enough when they test that correct `_paq.push(['someparam'], 'somevalue')` is called. I am not interested in covering all possible ways that some `setSiteId` can be made available; merely that my code has called or calls `_paq.push()` with the proper params. But, if testing the effect of the call is easier, I'd gladly pick that.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _paq = _paq || [];
    (function(){ var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://{$PIWIK_URL}/" : "http://{$PIWIK_URL}/");
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', {$IDSITE}]);
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
    _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; g.type='text/javascript'; g.defer=true; g.async=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s); })();
</script>
```

In this example, I would be interested in:

- `setSiteID` set correctly.
- `setTrackerUrl` has the correct url and protocol.
- `trackPageView` defined.
  etc.

#### Sidenote: not looking for unit-tests, but integration tests.

The unit-test side is pretty well covered. This is merely about expecting the correct `_paq.push()` calls when my extension gets certain configuration options, is integrated in a certain way or used in certain scenarios.

#### So, what testing strategy to take?

What should I test against? Regular Expressions? Parsing the JS with a JS parser? Running the JS with a runtime? Some mocking or stubbing trick that I overlooked?

Comment: What's the point of the test?  You test things in your application to showcase that business logic, specific to your app is working as expected.  There would be no need for a test like this, it's redundant.

Comment: @Anthony: An example: when the tracking code appears on a cart page, it should set a.o. variable `_paq.push(['trackEcommerceOrder', "A10000123")` to track an ecommerce order. Same for things like logged in users (get a UserId) and so on. Simpler example: when user of the plugin sets `Spree::Config.preferred_piwik_site_id ="1337"` I expect that to appear in the `setSiteId` in the tag. **Edit**: I don't understand your use of "redundant". Why is it redundant to test that the entire integration is done correct, aside from the unit-tests?